# How to redirect the daemon output to pipe with BusyBox's start-stop-daemon?

Tags: embedded-linux, busybox, start-stop-daemon

In my development environment which is an Ubuntu 20.04, the `start-stop-daemon` tool has the `-C --no-close` option to prevent closing any file descriptor in use. Using that option I can redirect the output of any program to a pipe as below.

```
start-stop-daemon --name MyProgram -C -S -b -x "<PATH_TO_APP>/app.elf" > "output.fifo"
```

> -C, --no-close
>
> Do not close any file descriptor when forcing the daemon
> into the background (since version 1.16.5).  Used for
> debugging purposes to see the process output, or to
> redirect file descriptors to log the process output.
> Only relevant when using --background.

However, the BusyBox version of the `start-stop-daemon` which I utilize on my execution environment doesn't have that option. See the `--help` page below.

```
Usage:
    start-stop-daemon [OPTIONS] [-S|-K] ... [-- ARGS...]

Search for matching processes, and then
-K: stop all matching processes
-S: start a process unless a matching process is found

Process matching:
        -u USERNAME|UID        Match only this user's processes
        -n NAME                Match processes with NAME
                        in comm field in /proc/PID/stat
        -x EXECUTABLE        Match processes with this command
                        in /proc/PID/cmdline
        -p FILE                Match a process with PID from FILE
        All specified conditions must match
-S only:
        -x EXECUTABLE        Program to run
        -a NAME                Zeroth argument
        -b                Background
        -N N                Change nice level
        -c USER[:[GRP]]        Change user/group
        -m                Write PID to pidfile specified by -p
-K only:
        -s SIG                Signal to send
        -t                Match only, exit with 0 if found
Other:
        -o                Exit with status 0 if nothing is done
        -v                Verbose
        -q                Quiet
```

**So, is there a way of redirecting the output while using the daemon tool?**

Comment: Either patch the Busybox' implementation or patch your daemon code to output somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying the code attached to this [ticket](https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=7430) which is implementing the option --no-close for the busybox version of start-stop-daemon.